# Python request library post function returning u"Unrecognized token 'filspoetfed': was expecting null"

Tags: python, json, http-post, jira

I have no idea what the error this command (the request line) throws means and there doesn't seem to be any information online about it.

```
 data = {
....:        'fields':
....:            {
....:            'environment': '- \\n- Repeated : 0 times',
....:            'description': '',
....:            'summary': 'Fill in Something',
....:            'project': {
....:                        "key": "QABL"
....:                 },
....:            'assignee': 'qa-auto',
....:            'issuetype': 'Bug',
....:            'priority': 'Major'
....:            }
....:        }

print header
{'content-type': 'application/json'}
```

> r =
>   requests.post("https://jira.some-company.net/rest/api/latest/issue/", 
>            headers=header, auth=requests.auth.HTTPDigestAuth('user', 'password'), 
>            data=data)

```
 r.json()
```

I tried to do a post request to JIRA using the request library, and the JSON response to r.json() looks like this...

```
 {u'errorMessages': 
    [u"Unrecognized token 'filspoetfed': was expecting 'null', 'true', 'false' or NaN\n 
    at [Source: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@10758d77; line: 1, column: 23]"]}
```

Anybody seen this before? There is no attribute 'filspoetfed' in my JIRA issue/JSON, so I don't understand. The only other possibility to my knowledge is that it is getting transferred into unicode when it gets submitted...but if that is the problem I don't know how to get around it. I did this in the same format as on the JIRA REST api page. Help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please post your code...

Comment: @bruno I added as much as I can to define the problem more clearly.

Comment: In for solution, too. Having the same issue

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I had a similar issue and solved it by changing the request

```
requests.post(url, data = json.dumps(data),auth=HTTPBasicAuth(username, password), headers= header)
```

The important thing is to use json.dumps(data) instead of data and in the header also included

```
'Accept': 'application/json'
```

Hope it works for you!
Have a nice day

Comment: Thank you, thank you so much! Spent 2 hours during midnight and finally understood what's the problem... (the `json.dumps` part). Do you know why a simple {"user": "blah", "password": "bleh"} doesn't work?